# Grails4 webapp is not starting anymore

Tags: grails-4

Today I have introduced few changes to Grails4 webapp (in security chainMap) but found out that the webapp is not starting anymore so I have stashed changes.

Stashing changes didn't help. I have ran `grails clean` but it also didn't help. I have checkouted out to the previous commit - didn't help. I have disabled spring security - it didn't help. I have deleted `build` and `out` directories - without luck. Tried to run via Intellij and console - both are stuck.

Th eproblem is that webapplication is not throwing any exceptions, it's just stuck during starting phase at:

```
<==========---> 83% EXECUTING 
> :bootRun
```

[image]

If I create a new grails webapp from scratch - it's starting fine.

How to debug it/solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Migration plugin and stuck migration blocking any further step caused it:

[image]

The issue is happening if you:

- start webapp via `grails prod run-app`
- make a change in the code and save
- restart the webapp when it's restarting by hotdeploy